# Cursor and output don't have the same color css

Tags: html, css, input, cursor

I want to personalize the input field so the cursor will have a blue color and the writing will be black. I want the cursor and the output when i write not to have the same color. How can i do that ?

Comment: Did you try something or you want someone to write it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if this is what you want?

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/8k1k0awb/21/)**

```
input
{
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: blue; //Change to whatever color you want
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}
```